# R code to use a function from .cpp file, based on Rcpp package

Tags: r, rcpp

I am confused by how to use the Rcpp package. What is the R-code to use a R function of newRcppVectorExample, after saving the following .cpp code, says example.cpp? The code is from http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.examples.html.

Do I have to create a package? Can I use the example.cpp directly? e.g. R CMD SHLIB example.cpp, then use the dyn.load function.

```
#include <RcppClassic.h>
#include <cmath>

RcppExport SEXP newRcppVectorExample(SEXP vector) {
BEGIN_RCPP

Rcpp::NumericVector orig(vector);                          
Rcpp::NumericVector vec(orig.size());                

std::transform(orig.begin(), orig.end(), vec.begin(), ::sqrt);

return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named( "result" ) = vec,
                          Rcpp::Named( "original" ) = orig) ;

END_RCPP
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to spend some time with the documentation, both for R itself (ie [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)) and Rcpp where you could start with the Rcpp-introduction vignette (which is also our [Journal of Statistical Software paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i08)).

In short, one extends R via the `.Call()` function which can access compiled code loaded via a package, or via `dyn.load()`.  But there is little point in me duplication that material here.

*Edit:* And given that you found the example you show in the [RcppExamples](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppExamples) package, here is how it is called in that same package:

```
RcppVectorExample <- function(vec=seq(1,9)^2, api=c("classic", "new")) {

    api <- match.arg(api)               # match to classic or new
    fun <- paste(api, "RcppVectorExample", sep="")

    ## Make the call...
    val <- .Call(fun,                   # either new or classic
                 vec,
                 PACKAGE="RcppExamples")

    val
}
```

This is slightly more complicated than usually because we can call either the example from the old and deprecated API (which is nevertheless still provided by the [RcppClassic](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppClassic) package) or the new API (for which you picked the code).

The key is that `.Call()` is used with a first argument for the C++ function named, followed by a set of arguments and a final argument pointing to the package in which the shared library is found.